# Custom event handler is not executed when using Angular UI Sortable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following piece of code:

```
  <ul ui-sortable ng-model="list">
    <!-- onDragStartHandler() is a global function, not part of $scope -->
    <li draggable ondragstart="onDragStartHandler();" ng-repeat="item in list">Item: {{item}}</li>
  </ul>
```

When `ui-sortable` ([github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)) directive is used, the code attached to `ondragstart` is not executed at all.

You can see this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OOw8Rt2jeo0qbqeE7Iqy?p=preview).

Any ideas how this event handler can be invoked as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, the ui-sortable manipulates the dom and removes the event handlers.

If you [look at their options](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable#options) - you can probably wire into the callbacks like so:

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list">
  <!-- onDragStartHandler() is a global function, not part of $scope -->
  <li draggable ng-repeat="item in list">Item: {{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

and your controller:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
  start: onDragStartHandler(e, ui)
};
```

Because onDragStartHandler is a global function - remember that you may need to $apply() the scope to see updates to bindings.